# Making scrapy spider follow links in given starting url

Tags: web-crawler, html-parsing, scrapy

I'm trying to build a simple spider with scrapy to navigate links starting from a given `start_urls` and inside the pages, scrape two items.

The goal: This is my [starting page](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories). here you see a list of amulets, I want to enter each of those amulets pages and inside those pages, scrape flavor text and item name.

I first built a working prototype that given a single amulet it scrape his data, now I want to expand it so it will do that for all of them at once but I'm struggling a lot on finding how to do so.

Here is the code so far:

```
import scrapy
from PoExtractor.items import PoextractorItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ArakaaliSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "arakaali"
    allowed_domains = ['pathofexile.gamepedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True))


    def parse(self, response):
        for link in LinkExtractor(allow=(), deny=()).extract_links(response):
          item = PoextractorItem()
          item["item_name"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()
          item["flavor_text"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[2]/span[3]/text()").extract()
          yield item
```

The `item_name` and `flavor_text` xpath does works well, it was extracted using Chrome "inspect element" feature but there is something in the rules or in the cycle of `parse` that doesn't work as this is the debut output:

```
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
2018-08-30 09:23:13 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories>
{'flavor_text': [], 'item_name': []}
```

That goes on for a while more and then the file containing the name and flavor is showing that:

```
flavor_text,item_name

,

,

,

,

,

,
```

And it keeps going for more than 300 rows.

Other useful information: Not all the links in the page leads to another page where item name and flavor are present so it's ok to find blank spots, my question is, why are they all white? Doesn't it follow the links to the game item pages?

Thanks in advance for every reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `parse` as a name for callback with `LinkExtractor`! I have fixed your syntax errors and added some `restrict_xpaths` to your code:

```
class ArakaaliSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "arakaali"
    allowed_domains = ['pathofexile.gamepedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_unique_accessories']

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths='//table[contains(@class, "wikitable")]//tr/td[1]//span[@class="c-item-hoverbox__activator"]//a[1]'
            ),
            callback='parse_details',
            follow=True
        ),
    )


    def parse_details(self, response):
        item = PoextractorItem()
        item["item_name"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[1]/text()[1]").extract()
        item["flavor_text"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/span/span[1]/span[2]/span[3]/text()").extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: That fixed most of the issues, thank you so much.
I will keep working from there, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first write a function to send requests to the game item pages(parse function itself) and in the second function add the current code in function parse.

You can send requests in many ways.

> 1.Since you are using scrapy, the following code can be used

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                          callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
```

parse_page1 will send requests to the url and you will get the response in parse_page2 function.

> 2.You can even send requests using python requests module,

```
import requests
resp = req.get("http://www.something.com")

print(resp.text)
```

Please comment if you have any doubt regarding this, thank you

Comment: Hello Agus, thanks for replying, do you mind clarifying a bit? I think I'm missing the "sending requests" part, If you don't wanna bother wriitng the code do you mind pointing me to a relevant specific documentation? Thanks in advance for whaterver option you go for!

Comment: @Peeveswozere Welcome, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as the answer

Comment: The answer is clear but doesn't fix the issue, also, you should not copy paste your own answer on different questions as this may be marked as spam or as an attempt to farm points.